# String to JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to convert a JavaScript string whose value is already formatted in JSON syntax, to a valid JSON object using `JSON.parse`.

```
// JSON formatted string
var string = "{'1451893035': 1.2,'1452670635':0.5,'1451720235': 2.5}";
// parse to JSON object
console.log(JSON.parse(string));
```

I'm currently getting this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '

Comment: You need to use double quotes "

Comment: I'm using double quotes to declare the string value, and single quotes within the string.

Comment: I know, you need to use double quotes to wrap the keys.

Comment: for starters...where do you get the string from? Chances are problem can be simplified at the source. Most programming languages will do all the needed serialization for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{'1451893035': 1.2,'1452670635':0.5,'1451720235': 2.5}
```

isn't valid [JSON](http://www.json.org/). You want:

```
{"1451893035": 1.2,"1452670635":0.5,"1451720235": 2.5}
```

Comment: Ahh, thanks! So JSON just can't handle single 'quotations'

Comment: Use a real JSON encoder to encode JSON. JSON is a lot stricter than Javascript, and manually-assembled JSON always ends up in catastrophe.

Comment: I can approve of "don't write your own JSON encoder", but "don't write your own JSON"? That's silly.